# PHP stream excel data to browser

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, phpexcel

I'm generating Excel documents throught PHP Excel.
Users are asking to output the content of the files directly to the browser.
I wrote the following code (after research via google) :

```
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xcel, 'Excel5');

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-type: applicaton/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=File.xlsx");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Pragma: public");
$writer->save('php://output');
```

This is resulting as follows :

> ��ࡱ�;��
>   ����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
>
> ��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
>   � ��B�=�%r8X"1��Calibri��� � ��� � ��� �
>   ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ��� � ���
>   � ��� � ��� � ��� � � �
>   �����8�������������������������������3f������ff���f����������������������������������̙��̙3f�3���������fff����3f3�f333�3�3f33�333�
>   iD07_12_ACT_N��g���W&File created at 06 Sep 2012 -
>   14:19:28 �
>   ��*+������&ffffff�?'ffffff�?(�?)�?�"dXX333333�?333333�?U}$
>   � >�@gg����� Root Entry��������
>   �F�ß:���ß:���Workbook������������
>   �F�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������

Instead of outputting the asked content as an excel-sheet I'm getting the encoded content of the excel-sheet.

Anyone who can resolve this problem ?

Thx

Comment: How many content type headers?

Comment: "Users are asking to output the content of the files directly to the browser." - isn't this what they get exactly? the code is a content of the Excel sheet outputted to the browser

Comment: Now the content is saved to a file on the server and they receive a link on the screen to the document.

Comment: Did u notice ur generating a excel5 writer in a xlsX file?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate an xls (Excel5) file try this:

```
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xcel, 'Excel5');    
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=File.xls");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $writer->save('php://output');
```

and if you want an xlsx (for excel 2007 or higher) file try this:

```
    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($xcel, 'Excel2007');    
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=File.xlsx");
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    $writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Tried what you advised but still getting the same result, browser still outputs as mentioned above

Comment: is it in internet explorer? Did u check @markBaker's answer, where he talks about ssl?

Comment: I used your Excel5 example and it worked after replacing `$xcel->save(` with `$writer->save(`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
```

should be sufficient for most browser (IE over SSL is an exception): does /Tests/01simple-download-xls.php work?

Do you have any output to the browser before the headers?

Comment: There's nothing outputted before the headers